# Multiline TextBox/Input Field In ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

To make multi line input field, Like ASP.NET MVC I have tried the following but didn't work in ASP.NET Core MVC:

```
public class Post
{
   [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
   public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

In the view:

```
<input asp-for="Body"  rows="40" class="form-control"/>
```

**Any Suggestion will be highly appreciated!!**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/319) in ASP.NET Core tooling repo.

The suggested workaround is to use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Body, additionalViewData: new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})
```

or

```
<textarea asp-for="Body" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 11):

There is also the option to use the `<textarea>`-tag

It would look like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Body">Opmerkingen</label>
    <textarea asp-for="Body" class="form-control" text-wrap:normal" type="text" placeholder="Please add your experience here"></textarea>
    <span asp-validation-for="Body" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```